# Visual Studio 2017 C++ OPEN SSL and cpprestapi linkage errors

Tags: c++, openssl, visual-studio-2017, cpprest-sdk

I am updating a solution up to Visual Studio 2017 toolset standards and I got to this:

```
**LNK2001** *unresolved external symbol "public: static class
std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class 
std::allocator<wchar_t> > const web::http::methods::GET" (?
GET@methods@http@web@@2V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?
$allocator@_W@2@@std@@B)*   

**LNK2019** *unresolved external symbol _OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf 
referenced in function "public: void __thiscall 
GatewayManager::EnableGatewayService(void)" (?
EnableGatewayService@GatewayManager@@QAEXXZ)*
```

I included all the *.libs, that were mentioned here in similar question, yet no success. Here is their list (there are few more, but they are definetely not related to those problems).

> brotlicommon.lib
>
> brotlidec.lib
>
> brotlienc.lib
>
> cpprest_2_10d.lib
>
> cpprest141_2_10d.lib
>
> Crypt32.lib
>
> Httpapi.lib
>
> libcrypto.lib
>
> libcurld.lib
>
> libeay32.lib
>
> libssl.lib
>
> mswsock.lib
>
> netapi32.lib
>
> ntdsapi.lib
>
> odbc32.lib
>
> odbccp32.lib
>
> Rpcrt4.lib
>
> secur32.lib
>
> shlwapi.lib
>
> ssleay32.lib
>
> wldap32.lib
>
> ws2_32.lib
>
> zlibd.lib

What more libs are required?

Comment: Are all those libs for the build type and platform you selected? I'm guessing Debug and x86, respectively

Comment: Yes, this is for Debug Win32, for Release the list is similar with minor changes.

Comment: Are the directories of these lib  files correct?

Comment: Yes, directories are correct.

Comment: You need to find out which library the error function calls. There may be other causes. Please refer to the document: [Linker Tools Error LNK2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=msvc-170#possible-causes).